# Kotlin Function with Genetic T Type

Tags: android, kotlin, generic-type-parameters

During a project development, I have encountered this weird function syntax

```
fun <T: Any> boo() { do something}
```

I am aware of T indicates a generic type and Any is a root class of all class in Kotlin and : implies class inheritance or interface implementation but what is T: Any?

Comment: Any? is the super type of Any. So _fun <T: Any?> boo() { do something }_ can be shortened to _fun <T> boo() { do something }_.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`T : SomeType` sets the upper bound of the generic type. `T` would have to either be `SomeType` or be some sub-type of `SomeType`.

In this case, `T : Any` sets the upper bound to be `Any`. While that may seem pointless, it does mean that `T` cannot be nullable.